# Linux can dual display but windows can't?

Tags: windows-7, display, ubuntu-12.04

I have two monitors, one that is hdmi-to-dvi and the other vga-to-dvi. I have an AMD HD Radeon 6900 series graphics card installed. I got Ubuntu to display dual monitors, but then I restarted for an update and then Ubuntu wouldn't even boot in recovery mode, it just kept cycling forever...displaying something about "timeout: killing [filepath] [hexadecimal]. So I tried booting into windows (7-professional) and it crashed and displayed this after rebooting: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, PAGE_FAULT-IN-NONPAGED-AREA. I went into Bios and reverted to the system defaults and ran system restore and it booted ok, but the dvi-to-dvi monitor would not display. I made sure my drivers were updated and catalyst was updated. Also through research discovered only one is for vga and the other is digital only, so I put the vga-to-dvi in the vga slot and so on. Neither windows or catalyst will detect the dvi-to-dvi montior. Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT:

Found out that booting into Ubuntu with only one monitor (using either monitor with either cable) worked perfectly fine. I could then add another monitor and it displays ok. However, it will, out of the blue, suddenly distort the display. At first I thought the computer crashed, but it is something with the video output from the GPU to the monitor because I pushed the power button and it would refresh every 5secs or so and I could see the "Ubuntu will power down in X seconds", even though it was horribly distorted. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Linux drivers are made from reverse engineering when the hardware provider does not help in that matter and are sometimes a lot generic. Windows has a **large** driver support, indeed, but may happen your card has faulty support for the end you are wishing for with your **current drivers** . try to obtain the most current drivers and retry setting the dual monitors. if it fails, check drivers from around the web that are tweaked somehow.